# How to refresh Nerdtree while switching the git branch

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, plugin-fugitive

This question comes from here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/1586

In a word, I'm using the two plugins: Nerdtree and vim-fugitive. What I need is when I execute `:Git checkout mybr`, I want to make Nerdtree be refreshed automatically.

So tpope told me that I could use `autocmd User FugitiveChanged`.

This is the first time that I see `autocmd User`. It seems that `User` means "never execute automatically". So I've tried to manually execute this in my vim: `:doautocmd User FugitiveChanged`.

However, nothing happend: no error but Nerdtree hasn't be refreshed either.

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User` means it is never executed by core Vim. Basically, it's a plugin who does `doautocmd User X`. Your business is to catch it with `:augroup` / `:autocmd`. So, yes, you did it wrong.

Comment: Could you please show me how to catch it with `:augroup`/`:autocmd`?